# Running script with relative paths from another directory

Tags: linux, bash, relative-path

I'm writing a script to compile a code. The sources are in many different directories. I'm going to release the source and I want it to be compiled by many other people. Thus in my script I use relative paths.
If someone runs the script on his machine, from the directory the script is in, like `./script` everything is ok. But, if the script is being run from another directory, like `./path/to/script` then the paths are not correct and the script doesn't work.
How can I overcome this?

Comment: Never use relative paths in scripts unless you are setting the current directory in the code itself.  Use absolute paths or append the required directories to `PATH` in the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### A simple starting point might be to add this to the top of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptdir="$(dirname "$0")"
cd "$scriptdir"
```

All following code will occur as if it was run inside the script dir.

Note that this is about causing the script to run

- **From the folder where the script is located**, and
- **Regardless of where the script is called from initially**

Which is what I suspect you want given that it's a script for compiling, thus it would placed in a very specific folder in the src tree (like a `configure` script or a form of makefile for example)

### **Rationale**

- `$0` is the full path of the running script.

  - From the `bash` man (my added formatting):

    > **Special Parameters**
    >
    > The shell treats several parameters specially.   These  parameters  may
    >          only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
    >         
    >    ....
    >   
    > **0**   Expands to the name of the shell or shell script.  This is set at
    >   shell initialization.
    >    If bash is invoked with a file of commands,
    >   $0 ***is set to the name of that file***.
    >    If bash  is  started with  the `-c` option, then $0 is set 
    >   to the first argument after
    >    the string to be executed, if one is 
    >   present.  Otherwise, it  is set to the file name
    >    used to invoke bash, 
    >   as given by argument zero.
- `dirname` returns the path of its argument
- `cd` changes the current directory

**Therefore,** every script with this code at the top, will be running as if `./script` was typed while currently in that directory.

## Coming at it from another angle

For measures of quality control and redundant error checking, you may want to implement a wrapper function that checks for a specific folder structure or presence of certain files that indicates everything is correct. (Say for whatever reason that `dirname` and `cd` command didn't work - which I have an example of for Mac down the bottom of this post).  This concept is two fold:

1. **You're doing stuff to set the current directory**
2. **You're checking that the stuff you did, worked.**

For example:

```
runcheck () {
versioncheck () {

head -n1 version | grep -q "### myapp V"

}

backout () {
echo "Problem verifying source paths.  Are you sure your archive is complete?"
exit
}

[ -d ./src ] && [ -d ./docs ] && [ -d ../myapp ] && (versioncheck) || backout 
    return
}
```

That code would check the following:

- The directory `src` exists in the same path as the executable script
- The directory `docs` exists in the same path as the executable script
- The directory `myapp` exists in the path one level down from the executable script
- That there's a file called `version` in the same path as the executable script, and that it's **first line** contains the string `### myapp V` (for example, for a `version` file which might have a top line that reads: `### myapp V1.4 ###`)

You could then place the command `runcheck` at any point in your script where it's important to verify you're in the right place:

## Complete implementation example:

```
#!/bin/bash

scriptdir="$(dirname "$0")"
cd "$scriptdir"

runcheck () {
versioncheck () {
    head -n1 version | grep -q "### myapp V"
}   

backout () {
    echo "Problem verifying source paths.  Are you sure your archive is complete?"
    exit
}

[ -d ./src ] && [ -d ./docs ] && [ -d ../myapp ] && (versioncheck) || backout 
    return
}

runcheck #initial check at start of script

## bunch of code
## goes here

runcheck #just checking again

## bunch of code
## goes here

runcheck #final check before really doing something bad

## end of script
```

---

**Side Note / Supplement:** This will work for `bash` when no thorough checking needs to occur to account for symbolic linking of the scriptfile, etc.. (which again... in portable source code tarballs, etc, I highly doubt is the case).

I suggest reading this thread: [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within)
 if you want or ever need a thorough understanding on this topic for more comprehensive applications of it.

Again I re-inforce using what you know tailored for what you need - for example it might be considered generally more **"robust"** to use `dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")"`, however, on Mac OS X, that would give you `readlink: illegal option -- f` , and is of no real benefit for portable scripts but more applicable for referencing locations of installed binaries that may be symlinked and/or contained in $PATH dirs

Comment: Thank you, very simple and does the job. If I have multiple scripts that call each other, is it safe that each one of them will have these opening lines? Will each script have its own unique `scriptdir` variable?

Comment: @Jona Yes, each individual running instance, whether it's the same script or other, with those lines at the top will have `$scriptdir` apply only to that file.  *Even if* for some crazy reason, `$scriptdir` was an exported environment variable in the parent shell, the setting of `$scriptdir` within the script will still update it's value for that script (not the parent shell environment)

Comment: @Jona I've added an additional supplement that might help check the setting of the scriptdir and subsequent current directory all worked well before executing any actual commands.  You would obviously modify this to suit your project

Comment: Congratulations for the completeness of your reply.

Comment: Might `cd "$(dirname $0)"` be more compact and clear

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez Not in my view.  1. The variable name makes it very clear what's happening.  2. You may want to refer to the `$scriptdir` multiple times in which case the command doesn't have to be subshelled each time and can be referred to itself _in_ a subshell

Comment: Lovely answer!!

Comment: how to make same but not for all paths in the script? some will be like this, and the passed as arguments will be related to pwd